# Access non-type template parameters in constructor

Tags: c++

I have a class that looks like this

```
#ifndef UNTITLED_FIXEDVECTOR_H
#define UNTITLED_FIXEDVECTOR_H

template<typename T, unsigned length>
class FixedVector {

public:
    FixedVector();

private:
    T data[];
};


#endif //UNTITLED_FIXEDVECTOR_H
```

But I can't in any way access `length` from its constructor:

```
#include "FixedVector.h"

FixedVector::FixedVector() {
    T[] data = new T[length]; //**NO LENGTH HERE!!!**
}
```

How can I access non-type template parameter from the constructor so that I can allocate data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to re-specify the template parameters

```
template <typename T, unsigned length>
FixedVector<T,length>::FixedVector() {
   data = new T[length];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can implement the body of your constructor in your header file :

```
template<typename T, unsigned length>
class FixedVector {

public:
    FixedVector()
    {
      data = new T[length];
    }

private:
    T* data;
};
```

Better yet, use `std::array` and not dynamic allocation if the length is known at compile time anyway, otherwise use `std::vector`.

Comment: You say that you have to implement it in the header file, which is true but you don't _have_ to define it inline, which is what your example does.  Also `std::array` may not be suitable if `length` is large.

Comment: @SirGuy "*Also std::array may not be suitable if length is large.*" Because..?

Comment: Oh, you may run out of stack space, in which case you would either have to dynamically allocate `data` or dynamically allocate `FixedVector`

Comment: @SirGuy To which I prefer the second option but that's personal.